# Show (dynamically created) Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, show

I have a Spinner:

```
     Spinner country_list=new Spinner(this);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     country_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I want to show it as popup for user to select. Do I need to use AlertDialog or is there even a simpler way?

**/EDIT:**
Actually, what I want is not Spinner. I want to get a list of countries when user clicks a button and then he or she can select a country. So basically his is the "second part" of Spinner - where a list shows in a popup. Should I use ListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I needed was

```
country_list.performClick()
```

to display spinner with a button click.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to show it as popup for user to select. Do I need to use
>   AlertDialog or is there even a simpler way?

-spinner already show as a pop-up and you can get selected value no need use alertDialog.

> [See This Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-spinner-tutorial.html)

Comment: Hmm, I found out I actually want ListView not Spinner. So I need ListView to show as popup. Now for that I suspect I'd need AlertDialog?

Comment: read your question what you ask ? if you need another thing then add in your question

Comment: should i use listview ? why ? android have already widget(spinner) for that and why are you use listview in pop up?

Comment: But I have no space for Spinner widget (the "first part" - one line with selected item and icon for dropdown). I only need the popup part when button is clicked - is that possible? :)

Comment: What is needed is country_list.performClick() !

Comment: its called spinner and display spinner as a pop up without click on spinner

Answer (score 1):

If you want the spinner itself to be in a pop up, you have to use a dialog.

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.addContentView(country_list, params);
    d.show();
```